# Executing system command asynchronously without blocking UI and exiting the process forcefully

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application on C# and I need to execute a system command that never exists (because it waits for you to press `Q`). I want to exit it forcefully after I receive the output first time and I also do not want to block the WPF UI so I want to do this asynchronously (I believe threads would make matters more complicated).

This is what I have now:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The above code has 2 problems: It blocks the UI and it never gets the output (the process won't quit).

Note: I used `WaitForExit()` because I need the output before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to run the process on a separate thread. It would prevent blocking UI.
2. Take a look at [Process.OutputDataReceived Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx), it occurs when an application writes to its redirected StandardOutput stream. So, the output can be taken even if the process is not stopped.

Comment: If using the process events, then the background worker is not required as the events occur async anyway when you invoke Process.BeginErrorReadLine() and Process.BeginOutputReadLine()